my discord bot does not produce any audio- ytdl-core-discord
I am just starting out and this is practically my first discord bot. I wanted to do something useful so I tried to create a music bot that via a youtube link plays the music for me, but even though this code gives no error, the bot enters the room and remains silent. I don't know how to solve this.
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const {AudioPlayerStatus, joinVoiceChannel, createAudioPlayer, createAudioResource, NoSubscriberBehavior } = require('@discordjs/voice');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core-discord');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('play')
        .setDescription('Play music from a YouTube link')
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName('url')
                .setDescription('The YouTube URL of the video')
                .setRequired(true)),

    async execute(interaction, client) {
        const channel = interaction.member.voice.channel;

        if (!channel) return interaction.reply('Devi essere in un canale vocale per eseguire questo comando!');

      //  const url = interaction.options.getString('url');
        const url=  'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BpwCJzPlz8k&ab_channel=SoloMusicLabel'

        try {

            const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
                channelId: channel.id,
                guildId: channel.guild.id,
                adapterCreator: channel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
            });

            const player = createAudioPlayer();
            const stream = ytdl(url, { filter: 'audioonly' });
            const resource = createAudioResource(stream);

            player.play(resource);
            connection.subscribe(player);
            player.on(AudioPlayerStatus.Idle, () => connection.destroy());
            

            interaction.reply('Play the Music!');

        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
            interaction.reply('There is a Error');
        }
    }
};

